# How to know which pages division visited

Tags: google-analytics

I try to use the next code

```
gtag('set', {
'custom_map':
    {
    'dimension2': 'division'
    }
});

gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-5', { 'division': '@Model.CurrentDivision.Name' });
```

But when I go to the "Pages" report I can't select Division to see which pages the selected division visited. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send it using directly this:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-5', {'dimension2': '@Model.CurrentDivision.Name' });
```

Comment: Michele thank you for the response. I've tried but I can't find how to group data by dimension2 on the google analytics. Maybe you know how to do it? Let's assume I want to see which pages were visited by dimension2...

Comment: In the all pages report just filter by page path you want and add your dimension as secondary dimension.